# Rails devise after_sign_in first time, check attribute and update another user one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

After a user's first sign in, I want to see if another user referred them by the `referral_code_used` column, and increase that user's `referral_count` + 1. Currently, a user is logged in and is taken to home_path

I have tried writing an after_sign_in_path_for(resource) method. This gets the job done, with respect to the referral count. The issue is this takes the user to `users/:id` path instead of home.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

    if resource.sign_in_count > 1
     puts "sign in count is greater than 1"
    elsif resource.sign_in_count === 1
      puts "sign in count is 1"
     if resource.referral_code_used != nil     
      referral_code = resource.referral_code.strip
      length = referral_code.length
      referral_code = referral_code[5..length]
      @user_referral_code = referral_code.to_i 

      if User.exists?(id: @user_referral_code)
        referral_user = User.find_by_id(@user_referral_code)
        referral_user.referral_count = referral_user.referral_count + 1
        referral_user.save
      end
     end
     puts "signin count = 1"
   end
   #redirect_to home_path
  end
```

When I put in a redirect_to home_path, it says `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.`  I'm guessing this is in the new sessions controller, which is handled by devise, but am unsure about that.

When I put it in the application controller, like below, there are no routing issues, but it calls it multiple times and adds more than 1 to referral_count:

```
 before_action :check_referral_code


  def check_referral_code
    if user_signed_in?
        if current_user.sign_in_count > 1
         puts "sign in count is greater than 1"
        elsif current_user.sign_in_count === 1
          puts "sign in count is 1"
         if current_user.referral_code_used != nil     
          referral_code = current_user.referral_code_used.strip
          length = referral_code.length
          referral_code = referral_code[5..length]
          @user_referral_code = referral_code.to_i 

          if User.exists?(id: @user_referral_code)
            referral_user = User.find_by_id(@user_referral_code)
            referral_user.referral_count = referral_user.referral_count + 1
            referral_user.save
          end
         end
         puts "signin count = 1"
       end
    end

  end
```

relevant routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
resources :users
get 'profile/home', to: 'profile#home', as: 'home'
```

What is the correct way to check the `referral_code_used` on first sign in, and credit the other user one time?   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing `redirect_to home_path` with `home_path`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.sign_in_count > 1
    puts "sign in count is greater than 1"
  elsif resource.sign_in_count === 1
    puts "sign in count is 1"
    if resource.referral_code_used != nil     
      referral_code = resource.referral_code.strip
      length = referral_code.length
      referral_code = referral_code[5..length]
      @user_referral_code = referral_code.to_i 

      if User.exists?(id: @user_referral_code)
        referral_user = User.find_by_id(@user_referral_code)
        referral_user.referral_count = referral_user.referral_count + 1
        referral_user.save
      end
    end
    puts "signin count = 1"
  end
 home_path
end
```

Comment: Yes! What is the difference between redirect_to and just putting the path? Aren't both essentially redirecting?

Comment: You just need to return the path in `after_sign_in_path_for` , devise will use this value and handle the redirection, you don't have to explicitly specify the redirection in this method. @gwalshington

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation! that makes total sense now. @bhanu